# Unexplained parse error in my script

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'

I am getting the above error in Code Igniter coding, mainly in line 2:

```
$this->load->model('helloworld_model');
$data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model-><span class="sql"> getData </span>();
$data['page_title'] = "CI Hello World App!";
$this->load->view('helloworld_view',$data);
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: You cannot mix a html tag in a function call.

Comment: Um, yeah, I think we found the problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
$data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model-><span class="sql"> getData </span>();
                                           ^
```

try

```
$data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model->getData();
```

Looks like some HTML made it into your PHP, probably while you copied and pasted it.

I assume you put the `**` in there to mark the line this is about. If not, remove them as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->helloworld_model-><span class="sql"> getData </span>();
```

This is clearly wrong. Something has mangled your code, possibly something in your IDE.

Write:

```
$this->helloworld_model->getData();
```

BTW I see you've tried to use Markdown bold inside a code block; unfortunately you can't do that.

Comment: hakre already addressed the issue.

Comment: @Sabeen: That is not grounds for downvoting. It does not matter on SO who is "first". Downvote only answers that are wrong and/or harmful.

Comment: @Tomalak i think its a pretty reasonable ground , how would you feel if everyone started copy/pasting your answers? You should have upvoted hakre and anything else u wanted to add, put in the comments instead of essentially saying pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @Sabeen: I didn't copy/paste anything at all. If you look carefully, our answers are just thirty seconds or so apart. Please read the Stack Overflow FAQ, quit telling me off, and remove your unfounded downvote.

Comment: This answer is the only possible answer and comes 40 seconds after hakre's one, it's hardly a dupe. + 1 to even out

Comment: @Tomalak .. not telling you off, just trying to point out that if you see that the issue has been addressed, for the sake of clarity you should remove your answer and support the answer which came in first.

Comment: @Sabeen: That opinion notwithstanding, this answer is correct and is thus _not_ eligible for downvoting. Please read the Stack Overflow FAQ, including some of the posts on meta. Also, please ensure that you leave a comment when you leave a non-obvious downvote like you did: I had to ask you to explain, which is not ideal.

Comment: @Tomalak for the record i tried to remove my up-vote but it was too late. No offense but please try to take it easy, in all circumstances common sense should prevail. Rock on and keep up the awesome work.

Comment: @Tomalak sorry about not not explaining the downvote, my bad!

Comment: @Sabeen Malik: Please take more care next time. The content on SO is shared amongst all users, you can not steal an answer. And different persons will formulate things differently which can only help the OP.

Answer (score 1):

your PHP does not parse, the `<` is unexpected. i'm not completely sure what kind of framework you are using here, but inserting a span directly into the PHP code will not work..